Bidirectional Pin Handling In Verilog
I'm very new to Verilog coding, and I'm currently facing a problem with bidirectional pin handling.
I'll put the code below.  In that, if mode is INPUT, I want to assign data in bidirectional pin to the register datatotop2, and if the mode is OUTPUT, I want to assign 7 to the bidirectional pin.
Can you please show me what is the mistake and how to handle it properly?
i made these changes and the problem remains same, if i give flags as input, modes are changing but the data is not getting, below is my code now
module ip_top(
clk,
data,
flagy,
flagz);

inout [31:0] data; 
input clk;
input flagy;
input flagz;
reg [31:0]datatotop2;
reg [2:0] mode;

parameter [2:0] INPUT  = 3'd1;   
parameter [2:0] OUTPUT = 3'd2;  

always @(posedge clk)begin
   if(flagy) begin
      mode <= INPUT;
   end
   if(flagz) begin
      mode <= OUTPUT;
   end
end

assign data = (mode == OUTPUT) ? 32'd7 : 32'dz;

always @(posedge clk)begin
    if (mode == INPUT) datatotop2 <= data; 
end
endmodule


I suppose you are assigning data to datatotop2 without checking whether mode is 1 or 0. Also, you do not say what output you are currently seeing. So, hard to say what is wrong.

hi @sai , does it interfere in other operations , if i assign data without checking mode? currently if i give flag as input, the modes are changing perfectly, but the data is not coming.


if the mode is OUTPUT, I want to assign 7 to the bidirectional pin

The following code is incorrect:
assign data = (mode == OUTPUT) ? 32'dz : 32'd7; 

You need to swap the order of the assignments to:
assign data = (mode == OUTPUT) ? 32'd7 : 32'dz;

There are other mistakes in your code that are likely causing problems for you.  It is surprising that you did not get compile errors when you ran the simulation.
You need to declare the mode signal, such as:
reg [2:0] mode;

You need to declare the clk_100 signal as well.  For example:
wire clk_100 = clk;

Currently, you are unconditionally assigning data to datatotop2 on every clock.  Perhaps you could condition it as follows:
always @(posedge clk_100)begin
    if (mode == INPUT) datatotop2 <= data; 
end 


This answer works and I will share the screenshots of output: https://i.sstatic.net/tCR6w5Jy.png, https://i.sstatic.net/ffwntm6t.png
